# HTTP Content-Encoding: gzip not recognized and wrong Content-Length

Tags: node.js, http, google-chrome, fiddler

I'm developing a nodeJS Proxy and stumbled over a strange behaviour of Google Chrome, which I also can reproduce in [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/).

If I send gzipped content to the browser, it doesn't recognize the different zipped/unzipped content sizes. But the content is still beeing displayed correctly.

Here a small piece of code to reproduce the problem:

```
var http         = require('http'),
    zlib         = require('zlib'),
    fs           = require('fs');


var Proxy = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
        var raw = fs.createReadStream('test');
        response.writeHead(200, {
                'content-encoding': 'gzip',
        });

        raw.pipe(zlib.createGzip()).pipe(response);
});

Proxy.listen(8000);
```

The file 'test' contains some dummy HTML, filesize is about 90KB.
It test the code like this:

```
$ curl localhost:8000 | gunzip
```

This works correctly so I think the nodeJS code is correct.

**The Problem**

[image]

This is a screeonshot of the gzipped response. The **Size** and **Content** values are nearly the same.
But I expect to be the received gzipped content (**Size**) to be much smaller then the unzipped content (**Content**).

Also, I do not see the expected "Content-Encoding: gzip" header. And the "Content-Length" header shows the length of the uncompressed file. I get the same results if I pipe the HTTP traffic through [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/)

[image]

This URL produces the expceted behaviour:

http://www.heise.de/js/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js

[image]

**So, what am i doing wrong?**

Why is Chrome showing the wrong sizes? 
Or does the nodeJS code send something wrong as response?

Comment: Clear your cache? Other code not being showing? Works fine for me.

Comment: Thats the only Code I execute. Cache is completly disabled. I'm glad to hear it works for you. Do you run any special beta/unstable version of node or Chrome?

Comment: If Fiddler shows that the content isn't GZIP'ed (and you haven't enabled the DECODE option in Fiddler's toolbar) then the content isn't GZIP'ed.

Answer (score 0):

Oh god, I got it working!
I dont' know why, but today I booted into my Windows development machine instead of Ubuntu.

As it seems, Chrome for Windows doesn't display or process the response correctly. 
Under Ubuntu, it works at the first try.

I want 6 hours of my life back.